# How to display a text on Line in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, line, arkit, raycasting

I have created small iOS Unity app that draws a line between 2 points. I am getting the distance as well showing in a `TextMeshPro`. Now I want to render this text on the line except showing it on somewhere else on the screen. This is how I draw the line and shows the distance.

```
GameObject start = points[0];
GameObject end = points[1];
measureLine.SetPosition(0, start.transform.position);
measureLine.SetPosition(1, end.transform.position);
var measurement = Vector3.Distance(start.transform.position, end.transform.position) * measurementFactor;
distanceText.transform.position = end.transform.position + offsetMeasurement;
var hasHit = Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit, float.PositiveInfinity,layersToInclude);
distanceText.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hit.normal);
distanceText.text = $"Distance: {measurement.ToString("F2")}cm";
```

But I want to render this `distanceText` on the line just like in the below picture.
[image]

In my case it just shows at the end point which also perpendicular to the line. How can I do that? Please help me. Thank you very much.

**UPDATE**
My current result is like this
[image]

Comment: Well you do `distanceText.transform.position = end.transform.position + offsetMeasurement;` so you set it hard to the end + offset ... what about rather e.g. `distanceText.transform.position =(start.transform.position + end.transform.position) / 2f + offsetMeasurement;` so setting it tot he center between start and end  + your offset?

Comment: Problem is my text shows perpendicular to the line. It doesn't rest on the line. If it is locate same as the plane of the line I am ok even it shows at the ending point. I want to know how to rotate my text to rest on the line wherever line renders

Comment: A line doesn't define a plane ... you would need 3 points to do so. Unity can not know on what surface you are drawing your line ... best you can do is rotate it so that the text's right/left axis is aligned with the line (by doing exactly that `text.transform.right = end.transform.position - start.transform.postion;`) .. however this still allows the text to be a) rotated 180° depending on the start and end point and b) it can still freely rotate around the line axis until you define how exactly it should face towards the user ;)

Comment: @derHugo Sorry for not being able to reply this since was working on a different project. I was able to align the text right/left axis with the drawn line. But I don't understand how to rotate it around line axis to readable for the user. I made another question here. Could you please have a look? link- https://stackoverflow.com/q/71962979/906414