# Rotate around multiple axis of a GameObject

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, 3d, augmented-reality

I am creating a measure app for iOS using Unity. I was able to measure distance between 2 points and show it in a `GameObject`. This is what I have achieved so far:
[![Measure something on the floor. User looking at top][1]][1]

[![Measure horizontally on vertical plane][2]][2]

My update method is like this.

```
    if(textObj.activeInHierarchy == true)
            {
                direction = pointTwo - pointOne;                    
                textObj.transform.right = direction; 

            }
```

`textObj` is the white color measure indicator. `pointOne` and `pointTwo` are the starting point and ending point of the line.

1. I want to show this measure indicator always readable to the user regardless of his position. But in my case(second picture), the indicator should be tilled towards the user around its X axis and its Z axis always should be perpendicular to the drawn line.Its Y axis should always face towards the inverse direction of camera.transform.forward. I tried adding

   `textObj.transform.up = -arCamera.transform.forward;`

before set the `textObj.transform.right = direction;` but that doesn't change any. But you can see in Apple Measure app the distance indicator is always readable to the user regardless of his position. How can I achieve this? Please help me.

Thanks!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQnmA.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxwln.png

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html

In you case you want the text object to look at the camera. The second parameter is a Vector specifying the upward direction, using the default value of `Vector3.up` it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did you mean add the LookAt() after textObj.transform.right = direction;?

Comment: You can probably use it instead of that line, but feel free to experiment with both :) I would try using only LookAt() first with 1 parameter, then add the second parameter in there to try different positions in the world.

Comment: it is pretty much doing the same internally ;) Basically it does `transform.forward = (target.position - transform.position); transform.up = up;`